# What does this stack trace possibly mean?

Tags: c++, debugging, segmentation-fault, stack-trace

I'm having segfault problem in my application written using C++ and compiled using GCC 4.3.2. It is running under Debian 5 x64.

The process crashed on the following line of code:

```
#0  0x00000000007c720f in Action::LoadInfoFromDB (this=0x7fae10d38d90)
    at ../../../src/server/Action.cpp:1233
1233            m_tmap[tId]->slist[sId] = pItem;
```

The stack trace that i got from the core dump is as follows:

```
#0  0x00000000007c720f in Action::LoadInfoFromDB (this=0x7fae10d38d90)
    at ../../../src/server/Action.cpp:1233
    ItemGuid = <value optimized out>
    ItemEntry = <value optimized out>
    pItem = (class Item *) 0x2b52bae0
    fields = <value optimized out>
    tId = 1 '\001'
    sId = 0 '\0'
    result = (QueryResult *) 0x7fadcae3d8e0
#1  0x00000000007c7584 in Action::DisplayInfo (this=0x0, session=0x7fadbdd44a20)
    at ../../../src/server/Action.cpp:1090
    data = {<ByteBuffer> = {static DEFAULT_SIZE = 4096, _rpos = 220043248, _wpos = 5469086, 
    _storage = {<std::_Vector_base<unsigned char, std::allocator<unsigned char> >> = {
        _M_impl = {<std::allocator<unsigned char>> = {<__gnu_cxx::new_allocator<unsigned char>> = {<No data fields>}, <No data fields>}, _M_start = 0x41200000 <Address 0x41200000 out of bounds>, 
          _M_finish = 0x0, 
          _M_end_of_storage = 0x7fad00000000 <Address 0x7fad00000000 out of bounds>}}, <No data fields>}}, m_code = 51152}
#2  0x00000000007d01a3 in Session::HandleAction (this=0x7fadbdd44a20, 
    recv_data=@0x25d83780) at ../../../src/server/ActionHandler.cpp:862
    pAction = (Action *) 0x0
    ActionId = 1079
    GoGuid = <value optimized out>
```

In frame #1, `Action::DisplayInfo` was called from `Session::HandleAction` on `pAction`. However frame #1 shows `this=0x0`, and frame #2 shows `pAction = (Action *) 0x0`.

I can't understand why this caused a crash. What does this possibly mean? `DisplayInfo` can't be called on a null reference !

Any help is most appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Why not? Quite obviously, you did call it on a null reference. You say it yourself pAction = (Action *) 0x0.

Knowing the code in question might be helpful.

Comment: @oefe: DisplayInfo seems to be called on null reference but see frame #0. DisplayInfo called it on the very same object. It means that DisplayInfo has worked just fine. Frame #0 and frame #1 are supposed to be on the same object.

Comment: C++ doesn't generate any kind of exception if you call a method on a NULL object pointer.  It will just blindly do it.

Comment: @Mike DeSimone: Thanks a lot. I didn't knew that. You could have posted it as an answer. I think everybody here gave me the correct answer and i was the one with not enough knowledge to understand. Thanks to all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
m_tmap[tId]->slist[sId] = pItem;
```

If that's the crash position, you're most likely indexing into non-existent data. If m_tmap is a `std::map` it's ok - but did you verify `slist[sId]` is a valid subscript?

Or - you called a member function on a NULL (or otherwise invalid)-Pointer and crash the first time you're accessing a member of the object directly, even if it's a few frames away. Are you sure `pAction` can't be NULL?

Stack traces needn't be valid. Firstly, you can corrupt them in your application. Secondly, optimizing compilers optimize that much away that the resulting stack traces are not reliable. Try a build with compiler optimizations disabled and use `assert` to verify your array subscripting is ok.

Comment: pAction can be NULL. So you are suggesting maybe the crash was caused because of calling DisplayInfo on pAction which was NULL? If that is the case then what does frame #0 mean?

Comment: Without the code, it's impossible to tell, but my guess is that the pAction was null, it called pAction->DisplayInfo, and DisplayInfo called LoadInfoFromDB.

Answer (score 2):

It's pretty obvious that pAction is null, and you called pAction->DisplayInfo.  Look at how the addresses in Action are all invalid in frame 1.  Other than that, it's hard to tell why without seeing some code, but I guess DisplayInfo calls LoadInfoFromDB either directly or indirectly.